# How to reuse Dagger Module

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

```
mNetComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder() 
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .build();

signInComponent= DaggerSignInComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .build();
```

This is how i am building my components but is it possible to reuse the AppModule created in DaggerNetComponent on DaggerSignInComponent

Comment: Did you just try it? Why do you want to reuse the same module? Did you have a look at `@Subcomponent` or `@Component(dependency=...)`, which both are also ways to have the same objects on 2 components?

Comment: Thanks i figured out. I am using dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having trouble with using dependency because of singleton and also i was using modules which caused troubles. took the youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Xk1LNrjarw&list=PLuR1PJnGR-Ih-HXnGSpnqjdhdvqcwhfFU&index=6